# How to use <Alt-Space> to open the window menu on Windows?

Tags: key-bindings, gvim, microsoft-windows

When I have to work on Windows I have the habit to reduce my windows with the key combo <kbd>Alt-Space</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> *(<kbd>Alt-Space</kbd> will pop the window menu and <kbd>u</kbd> is the shortcut to minimize the window and may change depending on the language of your system)*.

This is pretty useful but Vim takes control of all Alt- combinations, to increase the number of possible mappings which prevent me from using this combination.

**How can I do to use <kbd>Alt-Space-u</kbd> to reduce gVim in Windows?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(I actually found a solution while writing my question and thought it could be useful to other people)*

According to [`:h 'winaltkeys'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27winaltkeys%27) setting `winaltkeys` to `yes` should tell Vim to let the windowing system handle the combinations of <kbd>alt</kbd> and another key *(setting it to `menu` should tell Vim to let the windowing system handle <kbd>Alt</kbd> + a menu key)*. Unfortunately for a reason that I ignore, this option still doesn't let me use <kbd>Alt+Space</kbd> on Windows. So I found another option:

It is possible to create the following mapping:

```
nnoremap <M-Space> :simalt ~<CR>
```

The `simalt` command allows Vim to fake a Windows-style Alt keypress. This way when I press <kbd>Alt-Space</kbd> I get this convenient pop up menu and I then can press <kbd>u</kbd> to reduce my gVim Window.